# Infinite for loop on decremented by 2

Tags: javascript

I want to decrement the value **var i** by two but I am stuck in infinite loop.

```
for(var i=10;i>=0;i-2){
  console.log(i);
}
```

I found that the code given below is working but what is wrong with the above code.

```
for(var i=10;i>=0;i-=2){
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: In first case, value of `i` is not updated/assigned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down what happends in a for loop helps explain this.

1. iteration the var `i = 10` is called
2. iteration it runs `i-=2` which is short hand for `i = i - 2`
   (the wrong code `i-2` would never designate `i` with a new value)
   it would then check the condition in the middle of the for loop.
3. same as 2nd
   ...
   untill `i >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

> but what is wrong with the above code.

since `i-2` is actually not decrementing the value at all, so the value of `i` never changes in the loop and `i >=0` never fails, which is why the loop never ends.

Answer (score 0):

In the upper code, the loop incrementor is just calculating what `i-2` is. It never **assigns** the result back to *i*.

Answer (score 0):

the first code sets i to 8 (probably), but never changes i after that. no incrment(i++ or decrement i-- or any variation of the two)